# Does Ionic compile the Code to Native?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I've searched some times here but could't find an Answer to this.

Does someone know this and can explain how Ionic handles it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Does Ionic compile the Code to Native?* **NO**

Ionic is for developing Hybrid apps.

**What are Hybrid apps?**

> Hybrid apps are essentially websites embedded in a mobile app through
>   what we call a webview. They are developed using HTML5, CSS, and
>   Javascript, and execute the same code regardless of the platform in
>   which they run. They can, with tools like PhoneGap and Cordova, use
>   the native features of a device, like GPS or camera.

**What are Native apps?**

> Native apps are developed in the language required by the platform it
>   targets, Objective-C or Swift for iOS, Java for Android, etc. The code
>   written is not shared across platforms and their behavior varies. They
>   have direct access to all features offered by the platform without any
>   restriction.

Here is [**a nice article about it**](https://www.codementor.io/fmcorz/react-native-vs-ionic-du1087rsw).

Answer (score 3):

Cordova converts the project into a native which has only ONE Page, that is a WebView (WKV WEB View in iOS, etc). And all of the ionic code is run on that webview. Basically an ionic/cordova app is a website which looks like an app!

Comment: and what about swift ?

Comment: any source for that ?

Comment: the same thing, it converts into a single page (which is a webview/browser kinda)

Comment: You can find this when you open platforms/android or platforms/ios and checkout the code of the project. I found all this when I saw the project code

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for. i want to know how ionic it does and not the compilor. but thanks anyways

Comment: okay, could you please elaborate, so that I can try to help you more?

Comment: look at one answer before :)